# Find a Javascript variable definition with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to find a specific variable definition inside a site's HTML (in a  tag) I have the following code:

```
logResponse = scrape.post(url, params=logindata, headers=UA)
soup = bs(logResponse.text, 'html.parser')
x = soup.find_all('var my_post_key')
print(x)
```

The variable I am looking for is "my_post_key", but the soup.find_all function returns an empty list ([]). I suspect I am using it wrong, but am wondering how one would do this properly. This is how the variable is stored in page's HTML:

```
<script type="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-text/javascript">
var my_post_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
</script>
```

To recap, I am just trying to fetch the "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" value. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `find_all()` looks for _tags_, and "var my_post_key" isn't a _tag_.  Use `find_all('script')` instead, then search through those results.

Comment: @JohnGordon thank you, but then is there a way to "search through the results" as you said?

Comment: @Samuurai Pay attention that `find` and `select_one` will return only the first found `tag`, while `findAll` and `select` will return a `ResultSet`, and then you can parse the `element` using `.text` or `.string`, so you can split then according to your desired, something like `split('"')[1]` or using `regex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


html = """
<script type="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-text/javascript">
var my_post_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
</script>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
target = soup.select_one("script").string


print(target.split('"')[1])

#Or

match = re.search(r'key = \"(.+?)\"', target).group(1)

print(match)
```

Output:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```